# Invoking bean-style getters based on matching entries from a property file

Tags: java

I'm looking for an automated way to read a property file and invoke corresponding setters on a Java object.

```
#property file
person.firstName=firstName
person.age=11
person.address.cityName=cityName
...
```

Please bear with the following example object model.

```
public class Person{
   // below have getters & setters
   private String firstName;
   private int age;
   private Address = new Address(); // not null
}

public class Address{
   //below have setters and getters
   private cityName;
   ...
}
```

What I'm looking for

```
Person personObj = new Person();
MagicTransformer mt = new MagicTransformer();
mt.doMagic("filePath", personObj);
//now the personObj has all the properties set from the file.
```

It'd be great if the framework is clever about transforming standard types: *primitives, strings, enums, lists (primitives & strings), maps (primitives & strings)*

I explored before posting. Any search related to reading 'property files' had returned Spring's property placeholder, etc. I might have missed a resource. It'd be great if you could name a couple of frameworks.

Comment: I think you need JSON. Take a look at it.

Comment: It would also be nice if it wrote the code for, brought you a cup of coffee and put the bins out?  At some point, you're going to need to do some work. Sucks, I know.  Properties are only ever stored as `String=String`, but you could store meta data with each key, for example `person.firstname.type=java.lang.String`.  As to the other half of the question, you'll want to explore reflection...

Comment: So what is wrong with using Spring?

Comment: In my (unusual) case, the object is pretty big and using Spring won't do any good. I will end up with writing 50+ @Value{#...} statements.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about a single lib to do that all but it should be fairly trivial to:

- read the property file into a java Map (this should be fairly straightforward?)
- use the above and convert it to your POJO using either http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/ or using https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson (usin ObjectMapper)

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the data in xm; and using [xmlbeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/)

A simple example is

```
File xmlFile = new File("c:\employees.xml"); 

// Bind the instance to the generated XMLBeans types.

EmployeesDocument empDoc = 
    EmployeesDocument.Factory.parse(xmlFile); 

// Get and print pieces of the XML instance.
Employees emps = empDoc.getEmployees(); 
Employee[] empArray = emps.getEmployeeArray(); 
for (int i = 0; i < empArray.length; i++) 
{ 
    System.out.println(empArray[i]); 
}
```